# Solve $7\sin^2(x) - 9\cos(2x) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to solve for x in the polynomial

$$7\sin^2(x) - 9\cos(2x) = 0$$

I have tried approaching the problem in multiple ways. I am only looking for some hints, not the actual answer. Thanks :D

Comment: Do you know that $sin^2(x)=\frac{1-cos(2x)}{2}$ ? Is this enough?

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis I did not. Thank you! I will retry it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities of solving this one.

1. Using $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x)-\sin^2 x = (1-\sin^2 x) - \sin^2 x$  will give you an equation with only $\sin^2 x$ to solve
2. Using $\sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$ will give you an equation with only $\cos(2x)$.

Comment: Great! was able to work it out super easy from the first solution!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this all leading to the same answer:

**1) 7sin^2(x)−9cos(2x)=0**

```
using $cos(2x) = $cos^2x - sin^2x$
```

=> $7sin^2(x)−9(cos^2x - sin^2x)=0$   {as cos(2x) = $cos^2x - sin^2x$}

=> $7sin^2(x)−9(cos^2x - sin^2x)=0$

=> $7sin^2(x)−9(1 - sin^2x - sin^2x)=0$ {as $cos^2x = 1 - sin^2x$}

=> $7sin^2(x)−9(1 - 2sin^2x)=0$

=> $7sin^2(x)−9 + 18sin^2x)=0$

=> $25sin^2x=9$

=> $sinx=(3/5)$  or  $sinx= -(3/5)$

=> x = [0.643501109 rad](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=2%2b3&oq=2%2b3&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.11076j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=arcsin%283/5%29) or x = [36.8698976 degrees](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=2%2b3&oq=2%2b3&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.11076j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=arcsin%283/5%29%20in%20degrees)

**2)**   **7sin^2(x)−9cos(2x)=0**

```
 using $sin^2(x)=(1−cos(2x))/2$
```

=> $7(1−cos(2x))/2−9cos(2x)=0$

=> $7−7cos(2x)−18cos(2x)=0$

=> $7=25cos(2x)$

=> $cos(2x) = 7/25$

=> $2x= arccos(7/25)$   {which is [1.28700222 rad](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=arccos%287/25%29&oq=arccos%287/25%29&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6841j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%28arccos%287/25%29%29) or [73.7397953 degrees](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=arccos%287/25%29&oq=arccos%287/25%29&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6841j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%28arccos%287/25%29%29%20in%20degrees)}

=> $x=$ [0.64350111 rad](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=1.28700222/2&oq=1.28700222/2&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1914j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or x = [36.86989765 degrees](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=73.7397953/2&oq=73.7397953/2&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1895j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Ref : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: I'm not sure why you rejected the result $ \ \sin x = -\frac{3}{5} \ , $ as it is a valid result.  Moreover, each sine value corresponds to _two_ angles in the "principal circle", so there are in fact _four_ solutions to this polynomial in the interval $ \ 0 \le x < 2 \pi \ : \ \ \approx 0.6435 \ $ (the one you gave), $ \approx \pi - 0.6435 \approx 2.498 \ , \ \approx \pi + 0.6435 \approx 3.785 \ , \ \text{and} \ \approx 2 \pi - 0.6435 \approx 5.640 \ . $